# NameError: name 'html' is not defined

Tags: python, web-scraping, import

i do not undeeeerstand why this error appears and what cab i do to solve it. it s is my first time scraping uxing this mdthod so be cool (^^) pls. i thou it was the good methode, but...
thx for ur help[[image]]                                                          https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeuRR.png)

i tried  to import librairis

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots ([how to format code in posts](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)). [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: When you're typing in the interactive REPL, a blank line ends a block. So line `[4]` is not part of the `get_html()` function.

Comment: If you're going to paste code from a script to the REPL, you have to remove the blank lines except the ones between functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At [4] block you are not in the get_html function anymore.
So to make it work.

Try this:

**Put the [4] block inside get_html function in [3] block**